# Search hundreds of Word documents for specific string and numbers that follow it Notepad++

Tags: ms-word, extract

I need to search 800+ MS Word documents for the very first number in the document (e.g., "13150", which is always at the very top) followed by a specific term (i.e., "Map Zones") and the numbers that follow it in the next line such as:
Map Zones
48, 53, 57, 59 ,61

Ideally the output would be importable to Excel and be in the following format:
BpS Code      Map Zones
13150         48, 53, 57, 59 ,61

Is this super difficult?  Can I do this in Notepad++?

Comment: I don't think npp is capable of this. You'll need some sort of programming language and a library. For example: Java and apache POI

Answer (score 0):

Since you also talk about Notepad++ I'm assuming you're working with text files.
You could use grep. 
If you're using Windows you can use cygwin to run grep.

Show results on screen (*.txt means look at all the txt files in the current directory):

```
grep [your regex that matches what you want] *.txt
```

This will save to a file:

```
grep [your regex that matches what you want] *.txt >> youroutput.txt
```

Comment: OP states MS word documents. I suspect that there are .doc or .docx